# class not found error in joomfish

Tags: joomla

I'm creating website using joomla 3.0. I'm using joomfish component for multi language website. Installation is done but if I'll try to open the joomfish control panel it show the error like

> Fatal error: Class '' not found in
>   /var/www/muvacon/libraries/joomla/database/driver/mysql.php on line
>   397

I'm new to joomla please suggest any link to solve this issue. I have already searched many forum I did not get any solution.

Answer (score 1):

JoomFish has not yet been released for Joomla 3.0, therefore you will most likely get errors such as the one you provided. It is only available for Joomla 1.5 and 2.5 at the moment. They have a beta version (2.5) which is available for club members, however I'm not sure if they have done any testing on Joomla 3.0 with it.